# Modifying Manifest file in EAR inside Jenkins job

Tags: java, maven, svn, ant, jenkins

Is it possible to modify the Manifest.mf file inside .EAR/meta-inf/ folder within Jenkins not using Maven but via Ant ???

I have a CI job and Deploy job in Jenkins. The CI job polls SVN to pull the source code and build the .EAR. The generated .EAR file has manifest.mf updated with Jenkins build information (jenkins build info such as buildId, buildNumber, SVN revision number, Jenkins workpsace etc,). The Deploy job uses Copy artifact plugin which copies the .EAR file alone from a specific CI job build.

In my deploy job, an ant script target copies the .ear file from Deploy job workspace to remote staging server where the ear is deployed to WAS.

What am trying to do - Modify the EAR Manifest.mf in deploy job workspace to update additional information about the environment the file is deployed and the timestamp when the deployment is done. This is for auditing purposes. How can i achieve this from within the deploy job configuration in Jenkins.

Please advise !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this in ANT. You can use the `unzip` task, then use the `replace` task to change the file and can use the `ear` or `zip` task to create the EAR File.

Unzip Task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html

replace Task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

zip Task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html

EAR Task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html